# How can I retrieve the memory utilization of a pod in kubernetes via kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Inside a namespace, I have created a pod with its specs consisting of memory limit and memory requests parameters. Once up a and running, I would like to know how can I get the memory utilization of the pod in order to figure out if the memory utilization is within the specified limit or not. "kubectl top" command returns back with a services related error.

Comment: You should likely resolve your `kubectl top` issue, you can see the cpu and memory usage of your given pod like this: `kubectl top pod ${POD_NAME}`.

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl top pod <pod-name> -n <fed-name> --containers`

FYI, this is on v1.16.2

Answer (score 3):

> kubectl top pod POD_NAME --containers

shows metrics for a given pod and its containers.
If you want to see graphs of memory and cpu utilization then you can see them through the kubernetes dashboard.
A better solution would be to install a metrics server alongwith prometheus and grafana in your cluster. Prometheus will scrape the metrics which can be used by grafana for displaying as graphs.
[This](https://github.com/giantswarm/prometheus) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install metrics server to get the metrics. Follow the below thread

[Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "mem-example/memory-demo" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858746/error-from-server-notfound-podmetrics-metrics-k8s-io-mem-example-memory-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building ad-hoc metric snapshots, a much better way is to install and work with 3rd party data collector programs which if managed well gives you a great solution for monitoring systems and a neat Grafana UI (or likewise) you can play with. One of them is Prometheus and which comes highly recommended.

using such PnP systems, you can not only create a robust monitoring pipeline but also the consumption and hence the reaction to the problem is well managed and executed compared to only relying on `TOP`