# Get ServiceUnavailable from `kubectl top` with heapster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a managed kubernetes setup, called Cluster Container Engine (CCE), in the Open Telekom Cloud. Their documentation can be found [online](https://docs.otc.t-systems.com/en-us/cce/doc/download/20190103/20190103195909_573ac4f813.pdf).

My CCE has one master and three nodes which run k8s version `1.9.2` (more details below). I can access the CCE through `kubectl` and deploy new pods onto it.

The CCE has a deployment of `heapster` preinstalled. However, attempting to inspect node resource usage fails (I can observe the same effect for pod usage):

```sh
$ kubectl top pods
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services http:heapster:)
```

I've attempted all debugging steps I could think of (see below) and I'm still lost when it comes to fixing this. Any advice?

---

The `deployment`, `pod` and `service` items for `heapster` are present (outputs filtered to include only `heapster`):

```sh
$ kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
heapster-apiserver-84b844ffcf-lzh4b   1/1     Running   0          47m

$  kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                  AGE
heapster                 ClusterIP   10.247.150.244   <none>        80/TCP                                   19d

$ kubectl get deploy -n kube-system
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
heapster-apiserver   1/1     1            1           19d
```

To check that `heapster` does indeed collect metrics properly, I've ssh'd into one of the nodes and executed:

```sh
$ curl -k http://10.247.150.244:80/api/v1/model/metrics/              
[
  "cpu/usage_rate",
  "memory/usage",
  "cpu/request",
  "cpu/limit",
  "memory/request",
  "memory/limit"
 ]
```

**Pod Log Output**

Finally, I checked the log output from the `heapster-apiserver-84b844ffcf-lzh4b` pod:

```sh
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system heapster-apiserver-84b844ffcf-lzh4b
I0311 13:38:18.334525       1 heapster.go:78] /heapster --source=kubernetes.summary_api:''?kubeletHttps=true&inClusterConfig=false&insecure=true&auth=/srv/config --api-server --secure-port=6443
I0311 13:38:18.334718       1 heapster.go:79] Heapster version v1.5.3
I0311 13:38:18.340912       1 configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://192.168.1.228:5443" and version <nil>
I0311 13:38:18.340996       1 configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10255
I0311 13:38:18.358918       1 heapster.go:202] Starting with Metric Sink
I0311 13:38:18.510751       1 serving.go:327] Generated self-signed cert (/var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt, /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.key)
E0311 13:38:18.540860       1 heapster.go:128] Could not create the API server: missing clientCA file
I0311 13:38:18.558944       1 heapster.go:112] Starting heapster on port 8082
```

---

**Cluster Info**

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.2-CCE2.0.7-B003", GitCommit:"302f471a1e2caa114c9bb708c077fbb363aa2f13", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-20T03:27:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl get nodes
192.168.1.163   Ready    worker       19d   v1.9.2-CCE2.0.7-B003
192.168.1.211   Ready    nfs-server   19d   v1.9.2-CCE2.0.7-B003
192.168.1.227   Ready    worker       19d   v1.9.2-CCE2.0.7-B003
```

All nodes use `EulerOS_2.0_SP2` with kernel version `3.10.0-327.59.59.46.h38.x86_64`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io "mem-example/memory-demo" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858746/error-from-server-notfound-podmetrics-metrics-k8s-io-mem-example-memory-demo)

Answer (score 0):

```
I0311 13:38:18.510751       1 serving.go:327] Generated self-signed cert (/var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt, /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.key)
```

It seems like your API server is running on HTTP but heapster has a https url configured. You need to set the `--source` parameter to override the Kubernetes master like described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/source-configuration.md):

```
--source=kubernetes:http://master-ip?inClusterConfig=false&useServiceAccount=true&auth=
```

BTW: heapster has been deprecated and it is advised to switch to [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server).